# Firestore Document Typescript doc.data() undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently cleaning up a bit of code and rewritting a lot in typescript. What I found what made me curious is the following code:

```
    const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(userId);
    const userDoc = await userRef.get();

    if (userDoc.exists) {
        const userData = userDoc.data();

        const currentUserBalance = userData.balance ? userData.balance : 0;
    }
```

Now Typescript will complain that `userData` is possibily `undefined`, but the Documents `.data()` cannot be undefined when I check for the document existing above in my `if` block. Just curious on why that happens and if I have a logic issue here or not.

Comment: If the provided answer was helpful for you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have any knowledge of the relationship between `exists` and `data()`.  It just knows the signature of `data()` says that the return value can be DocumentSnapshot or undefined.  So, you must satisfy the compiler by either:

1. First checking for "truthiness", then use the results if so:

```
const data = userDoc.data()
if (data) {
    // In this block, data is now typed as just DocumentData,
    // undefined is no longer an option.
}
```

2. Telling TypeScript that you know for sure that the results will be "truthy" by using the `!` operator:

```
const data = userDoc.data()!  // data is now typed as just DocumentData
```

Comment: @Doug Stevenson you actually only need one exclamation mark [as documented here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: @lukasgeiter That's what I get for using Kotlin as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even though Firestore adapters both for Node.js and the web are written mainly in TypeScript, they aren't designed for the language.

To solve the problem, I wrote [Typesaurus](https://github.com/kossnocorp/typesaurus), TypeScript-first ORM (or ODM if you wish) that solves this problem:

```
import { get, collection } from './src'
type User = { name: string }
const users = collection<User>('users')

async function main() {
  const user = await get(users, 'qwe') // get will return document or undefined
  if (user) {
    console.log(user.data.name) // user is Doc<User>
  } else {
    // user is undefined
  }
}

main()
```